# Change Author name after pull request is merged

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to change the author name of the commit after your commit is merged for the pull request that i opened.  I understand that amend to a commit can do the change to author name.

But how to do handle such situation after pull requests are merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to rewrite that commit, resulting in conflicts for anyone who has already seen that commit. Hence it is generally discouraged to rewrite (or rebase) commits once they are published.

That being said, you can easily change the author during a `git commit --amend` by setting the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` environment variable first. Make sure you reset the environment variable afterwards (or just define it locally for the single amend command), otherwise all new commits will also take that author name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I understand this that i need to rewrite the commit.  But do i need to open the pull request again to merge it with the  Repo where the bad commit was merged previously?  Is there no other way ?

Comment: No, you don’t need to open it again. You can either just auto-merge it using GitHub’s web interface and then amend the commit, or you [merge it manually](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request#merging-locally) to begin with and close the pull request manually then (that’s probably better because the commit you are rewriting won’t appear in the repository).

Comment: thanks, i think this should do.  My case looks a bit diff.  The repo i contributed was rails and to manage author names they have this https://github.com/fxn/rails-contributors/blob/master/app/models/names_manager.rb

Comment: Worth noting that if there is an explicit merge commit, if you overwrite the author, it will disappear from gitlog.